# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layout requested for visible navigation bar Xcode 15.0 Crash

Tags: xcode, xcode15, ios17

I update my Xcode to 15.0 and run application. When run application on iOS 17 my app is crashing with this Error:

> Assertion failure in -[UINavigationBar layoutSubviews], UINavigationBar.m:3 849 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layout requested for visible navigation bar

It happens only on iOS 17 with Xcode 15.0. With Xcode 14.3 and iOS 17 - no. With Xcode 15 and iOS 16.4 - no.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Layout requested for visible navigation bar, <UINavigationBar: 0x15bd34ee0; frame = (0 47; 428 44); autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x2813b9f40>> delegate=0x15c049e00 standardAppearance=0x2837b03c0 scrollEdgeAppearance=0x2837b02a0 compactAppearance=0x2837b0540 compactScrollEdgeAppearance=0x2837b0240, when the top item belongs to a different navigation bar. topItem = <UINavigationItem: 0x15bf26070> titleView=0x160f04840 style=navigator backBarButtonItem=0x15bf5f4d0 rightBarButtonItems=0x281c93f90, navigation bar = <UINavigationBar: 0x15bd05d60; frame = (0 47; 428 44); autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x2813be380>> delegate=0x15c056800 standardAppearance=0x2837fd5c0 scrollEdgeAppearance=0x2837fd7a0 compactAppearance=0x2837fd080 compactScrollEdgeAppearance=0x2837ff780, possibly from a client attempt to nest wrapped navigation controllers.'

Need help :)

I already set `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` but it's not helped

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm facing the same issue on iPhone but not on the iPad, there's a Split View and 2 possible navigation controller which I will switch between using splitViewController.showDetailViewController(navigationController2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For us, we've also experienced the same crash when the app is compiled using Xcode 15.0.1 and running on iOS 17 (work fine with Xcode 14.x). Our app moves view controllers from one navigation controller to another navigation controller using the following code:

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = oldNavigationController.viewControllers
oldNavigationController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

The crash is immediately gone after we've inserted the following line of code before dismissing the oldNavigationController:

```
oldNavigationController.viewControllers = [UIViewController]()
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and the reason was in `UISplitViewController`'s delegate: in `splitViewController(_:collapseSecondary:onto:)` when I moved the view controllers from a secondary navigation controller to the primary one I didn't remove them from the secondary navigation controller. After I started to remove them, the crash has gone. So try to check the places where you change the view controllers' parents.

Comment: Did you faced with this crash also in Xcode 15?

Comment: @Mark Yes. Xcode 15 iOS 17.

Comment: this solved my issue on Pro Max device and simulator by setting empty array to viewControllers of secondary navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

After I removed/commented this line, the crash has gone.

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
```

**YOU NEED TO REMOVE/COMMENT ONLY**

- I moved this line to the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but this **didn't
  help**
- I wrote `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` but this also
  **didn't help**

Answer (score 0):

## Modern `UISplitViewController` can also have this crash

This can also happen with a modern `UISplitViewController`, created using `init(style:)`.

In this case, the changes in `splitViewController(_:collapseSecondary:onto:)` suggested in other answers are unlikely to work, as that delegate method is not (supposed) to work with the modern style-based split views.

In my case, I found that the issue presented with the same builds as mentioned here: builds from Xcode 15+ with iOS 17+ devices only. The crash happened only when the view was collapsed, when the secondary vc was set and shown. Setting it alone was not sufficient to cause the crash.

As mentioned in the error message, it was due to "... a client attempt to nest wrapped navigation controllers."

### Solution: ensure the split view is not inside a UINavigationController

The nesting was due to my `UISplitViewController` was presented *inside* a navigation controller. Presenting the split view controller as the root of its tab resolved the issue.

#### Finding it: ruling out auto-wrapping

I created the child navigation controllers, rather than relying on the [auto-wrapping in a `UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller#1653114), and made sure these weren't being double-wrapped.

The auto-wrapping caused other issues with the navigation stack, namely unwanted back navigation to previously selected entities, when collapsed, rather than going back to the primary view controller. I did try using it to resolve the crash, passing a plain non-navigation view controller to the `setViewController(_ for:)` call, and the crash happened just the same.

Answer (score 0):

**just change the uiviewcontroller into uinavigationcontroller and present it**

**Example**
let presetingVC = any UIViewController

let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: presetingVC)

navigationVC.navigationBar.isHidden = true

baseVC.present(navigationVC, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened when I was trying to display (`showDetailViewController`) `NavigationController` which doesn't present any ViewController (basically NavigationController.viewControllers array was empty).

Answer (score -2):

you need bring forward ： [self setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; if you custom NavigationBar
because xcode15 excute timing bring forward

Comment: The question is for Swift, while your answer is: 1. Objective-C; 2. giving a solution that was already provided

Comment: @Cristik Countless questions tagged with Objective-C have Swift answers. I see nothing wrong with posting an Objective-C answer on a Swift question. Note that I'm only addressing the generality of that part of your comment. I am not addressing the usefulness of this specific answer in any way.

Comment: @HangarRash Giving Swift answers to Objective-C questions makes more sense, as the vast majority of project migrate from Objective-C to Swift, not the other way around. Otherwise I would've poke those answers also.